# Emacs failed to load initialization file

Tags: emacs, initialization, package

I am using Emacs 25.3 under windows 10 platform.

It works fine until one time I started it and got the following message:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘ 
c:/Users/shore/AppData/Roaming/.emacs’:

Wrong type argument: listp, <html>

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

As instructed I used --debug-init option to start and got the following message:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp <html>)
  package--read-archive-file("archives/gnu/archive-contents")
  package-read-archive-contents("gnu")
  package-read-all-archive-contents()
  package-initialize()
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "c:/Users/shore/AppData/Roaming/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 275
  load-with-code-conversion("c:/Users/shore/AppData/Roaming/.emacs" "c:/Users/shore/AppData/Roaming/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
    [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" initialization format-message "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'" "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Can anyone tell me where my problem is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that when it tried to read file `archives/gnu/archive-contents` it expected to read Lisp (more specifically a Lisp list). Instead, it encountered `<html>` (presumably text in the file).

A guess is that you somehow downloaded or picked up an HTML file (perhaps one that describes the archive file or that has links to download it) instead of downloading or picking up a file of Lisp code. Try once again to obtain that archive file.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. However, I'm not familiar with elisp, so I may need some more assistant on how to find the HTML file and how to obtain the archive file. If you do not mind, please help me on that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi I found it, it actually start with 
<html>
<head>
So should I simply delete it or try to download a file from the net?

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, I actually fixed the problem by removing the html file under the directory. Thanks a lot!!!!